# Need to know if this JavaScript validation for form is correct

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

I have a form on my uncles website that is created in an asp page. The asp page submits to a php page. This is the only way I could work around FastHost actually letting the email get through to his mail.

I am trying to add validation in the head section in the form but this doesn't seem to be working.

The code within the head section and form are as follows:

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateForms() {
  var x=document.forms["myForm"]["frmname"].value;
  if (x==null || x=="") {
    alert("First name must be filled out");
    return false;
 }

  var x=document.forms["myForm"]["frmemail"].value;
  var atpos=x.indexOf("@");
  var dotpos=x.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
    alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    return false;
  }
} 

</script>
```

The Form:

```
<form action="sendmail.php" onsubmit="return validateForms();" id="myForm" method="post">
                    <table  border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" class="text">
                        <tr>
                            <td><p>Name : * </p></td>
                            <td><input name="frmName" id="frmName" type="text" class="textbox" value="<%=frmName%>" size="35" title="Required" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p>Email : *</p></td>
                            <td><input name="frmEmail" id="frmEmail" type="email" class="textbox" value="<%=frmEmail%>" size="35" title="Required" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p>Phone : </p></td>
                            <td><input name="frmPhone" id="frmPhone" type="text" class="textbox" value="<%=frmPhone%>" size="35" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p>Address :</p></td>
                            <td><input name="frmAddress" id="frmAddress" type="text" class="textbox" value="<%=frmAddress%>" size="35" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p>How did you hear about us :</p></td>
                            <td><select name="frmReferral" id="frmReferral" class="block" style="width: 180px">
                            <option value=""> - SELECT - </option>
                            <option value="Magazine advert"<%if frmReferral = "Magazine advert" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Magazine advert</option>
                            <option value="Booklet advert"<%if frmReferral = "Booklet advert" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Booklet advert</option>
                            <option value="Web search"<%if frmReferral = "Web search" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Web search</option>
                            <option value="Web directory"<%if frmReferral = "Web directory" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Web directory</option>
                            <option value="Newspaper"<%if frmReferral = "Newspaper" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Newspaper</option>
                            <option value="TV"<%if frmReferral = "TV" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>TV</option>
                            <option value="Other"<%if frmReferral = "Other" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Other</option>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><p>Do you require a call back :</p></td>
                            <td><select name="frmCallback" id="frmCallback" class="block" style="width: 180px">
                            <option value=""> - SELECT - </option>
                            <option value="Morning"<%if frmCallback = "Morning" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Morning</option>
                            <option value="Afternoon"<%if frmCallback = "Afternoon" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Afternoon</option>
                            <option value="Not Required"<%if frmCallback = "Not Required" then%> selected="true"<%end if%>>Not Required</option>
                            </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left" valign="top"><p>Enquiry :</p></td>
                            <td><textarea name="frmEnquiry" id="frmEnquiry" cols="27" rows="4" class="textbox" style="width: 180px"><%=frmEnquiry%></textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                            <td align="right"><input name="submit" type="submit" value=" Send " class="submit">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input name="reset" type="reset" class="submit"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                </form>
```

I would appreciate any help with this. Thanks

Comment: What's not working?  What is happening?  Do you have a functional website we could see?

Comment: @BrianHoover the JavaScript is not even being read in the head section the form just submits to the PHP page which the host provided. This PHP page has it's own email validation but I want it to read the JavaScript beforehand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

frmname and frmemail need to be camel-cased like in their input tags.

```
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["frmName"].value;
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["frmEmail"].value;
```

Comment: thank you, well spotted. I'm half asleep I will accept your answer in 4 minutes